# How to use \citet when using \bibliographystyle{spphys}?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I downloaded this template from Springer; when I use `\citet` with `\bibliographystyle{spphys}`, it returns something like `(author?)[12]`. I want the number between the bracket, but I don't know why it doesn't show the name of the author? I'd really appreciate your help.

```
% proceed on the \documentclass line
% your LaTeX will extract the file if required
\begin{filecontents*}{example.eps}
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 19 19 221 221
%%CreationDate: Mon Sep 29 1997
%%Creator: programmed by hand (JK)
%%EndComments
gsave
newpath
  20 20 moveto
  20 220 lineto
  220 220 lineto
  220 20 lineto
closepath
2 setlinewidth
gsave
  .4 setgray fill
grestore
stroke
grestore
\end{filecontents*}
%
% \RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%
%\documentclass{svjour3}                     % onecolumn (standard format)
%\documentclass[smallcondensed]{svjour3}     % onecolumn (ditto)
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)
%\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
%
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%
% \usepackage{graphicx}
%
% \usepackage{mathptmx}      % use Times fonts if available on your TeX system
%
% insert here the call for the packages your document requires
%\usepackage{latexsym}
% etc.
%
% please place your own definitions here and don't use \def but
% \newcommand{}{}
%
% Insert the name of "your journal" with
% \journalname{myjournal}
%

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math

\begin{document}

\citet{Bell}

\bibliographystyle{spphys}       % APS-like style for physics
\bibliography{library}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `spphys` doesn't appear to be on CTAN. The versions I found floating around on the web all do not appear to support `natbib` (specifically `natbib`'s author-year citation handling), so `\citet` and the option `authoryear` will not work as expected. There is little you can do here if you are forced to use `spphys`. Either choose a style that supports `natbib` (not sure if that is possible if you are going to submit to Springer, you probably ought to use their template) or don't use `natbib`'s `\citet` or `authoryear` features.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have to use `spphys`. Is there any way to use `\citet` without `natbib`?

Comment: Not really, no. `spphys` simply does not expose the author to LaTeX in a manner that is usable for citation commands.